# PHP script (XAMPP) called from React app won't execute - shows php code

Tags: php, reactjs, apache, xampp

I've installed XAMPP on my Windows 10 machine.

Apache works (call to any `.php` file in `htdocs` in browser gives desired results - PHP gets executed).
But when I call `.php` from my `React` app (devserver on `localhost:3000`) in devtools I see that it returns just php script by itself.

I also tried adding `"proxy": "http://localhost",` to my `package.json`, but didn't get desired results.

I think there's something with Apache configuration, but don't know what exactly.

Comment: Share the code where you make the request

Comment: @B001ᛦ well, php is a part of `XAMPP` and as I mentoned above if I run `localhost/ .php` file in browser it works fine

Comment: @BrettGregson  here's the code from my `context.js` :
`getProductsByCategoryId = () => {
      const url = process.env.PUBLIC_URL+"/api/api/products/products.php?category="+this.state.categoryId;
      axios.get(url)
        .then(...)
    }
`

Comment: Are you quering a database in your PHP file? If so you need to turn on MySQL service as well

Comment: @KebabProgrammer I'm quering a database on a remote server where SQL server is started.

Comment: Have you verified that the `url` value you are creating is actually correct? If you log that and then request it via browser address bar, do you still get the correct result? That your server would handle a request to the same URL differently based on specific requests characteristics (some headers react adds maybe) is conceivable, of course - but that it does so without having been specifically instructed to do so, rather less.

Comment: @misorude Yes, it it correct, because I get the code of that php file back (visible in Chrome devtools -> Network)

Comment: And when you open that exact URL in a new tab, directly from the network panel via the context menu, you get the same result? Or the expected output?

Comment: @misorude not exactly. It points to `http://localhost:3000/api/api/products/products.php?category=0`, so I just can "download" the `products.php` file. 
Probably, what I need is to forward it from `localhost:3000` to just `localhost`, or `localhost:80` where Apache is listening, but  `"proxy": "http://localhost"`, in my `package.json` doesn't help

Comment: Sounds rather like you should not be using `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` to create that URL in the first place. I guess that is supposed to be the public URL of your react app, and therefor likely to contain `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: @misorude Removing `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` doen't solve problem, and I think I do need it when I put code into build and production, because app is in the subfolder of website. Also I need to mention that `build` version on the remote server works fine, so it's the problem only on local dev server

Comment: You are trying to make a request to a different origin, so you need to explicitly specify that origin. If you just specify a relative URL, then this will of course be resolved to an absolute one using the current origin - but that is not what you want, because that is the wrong one. If the code as shown works on your live system, then you must have a significantly different setup there, than you have local.

Comment: @misorude well, dev server (node on localhost by create-react-app setup) runs on port `3000`, and local apache is on port `80`.
After build (by Webpack) and deploy everything runs of port 80 and there's no `src` and `public` folders, so it's all same origin.
So I need to fugure out how can I proxy those request to .php including `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in the URL